# prove that $|{\{X\subseteq\mathbb{N}|\ |\mathrm{X|={\aleph_{0}}}\}}| = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to prove that:

$$|{\{X\subseteq\mathbb{N}|\      |\mathrm{X|={\aleph_{0}}}\}}| = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$$. it's allowed to use the fact that $|P(\mathbb{N})|=2^{\aleph_{0}}=|\mathbb{R}|$ - this is the original form of the Q.

It's written terribly, and that's a part of why I failed to prove it. the Q is essentially:
prove that the cardinality of the SET of all the infinite sub-sets of $\mathbb{N}$ (referred as $\mathrm{X}$), is equal to $2^{\aleph_{0}}$.
further more, I'd rather prove that without using onto/one-to-one function, only if possible, in the tools of elementary set theory (meaning, without ZFC)

Comment: Twice you wrote a weird (for me) right curly parentheses $\;\}\;$ ...what does it mean? And also: $\;X\subset\Bbb N\implies |X|\le|\Bbb N|=\aleph_0<2^{\aleph_0}\;$ ...

Comment: fixed it. as I explained, its the set of ALL X's

Comment: Again, your set is **empty**, as there is no subset of the naturals with cardinal equal to $\;2^{\aleph_0}\;$ ...Perhaps you meant the set of all infinite subsets of $\;\Bbb N\;$ ...or something of the like? And edit also the question's header.

Comment: You also probably mean $|X|= \aleph_0$.

Comment: correct. fixed it

Comment: Your question is not different from the duplicate. It is *exactly* the same question. The wording is different, yes. But you are asking how many subsets of $\Bbb N$ are infinite, because the subsets of $\Bbb N$ which are infinite are exactly those that have cardinality $\aleph_0$. If you don't see why, then it is a good exercise to figure out this thing before moving forward.

Comment: Not only the question is the same, the answer you've received **and accepted** from DonAntonio is exactly the same answer I gave to the duplicate. So I am quite befuddled as to why you disagree that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea:

Prove first that the set of all **finite** subsets of the naturals is countable:

$$\;\left|\left\{\,X\subset\Bbb N\;/\;|X|<\aleph_0\,\right\}\right|=\aleph_0$$

and then use directly that $\;|P(\Bbb N)|=2^{\aleph_0}\;$

Comment: What does the `/` stand for here? Is it a wobbly replaced for `\mid`? Is it the leaning mid-line of Pisa? :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Take a wild guess what could it be...:)

Comment: I'd say a fraction. Because you're not a set theorist, and you're unaware of the fact that fractions are not used in set theory like that. :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah...because, you know, you need to be a set theorist to know how sets are written. Right.

Comment: Apparently! :))

Comment: @AsafKaragila בעצם זה לא משנה: השאלה נסגרה, תשובתי התקבלה...זהו